# ¿como puedo posicionar los iconos de las redes sociales en la parte superior?

Tags: html, css, posicionamiento

Tengo horas intentando como hacer para que las resdes sociales queden arriba (donde esta el circulo rojo) y no logro hacerlo. los coloque dentro de un contenedor, les coloco posicion: absolute; top: 0 y así es peor, ya que se salen del flujo. no entiendo xq se colocan abajo y no quedan arriba, todo es por la imagen que tengo al lado.

EDITADO: ES IMPORTANTE ACLARAR QUE ESTO ES PARA UNA PLANTILLA DE CORREO, POR TAL MOTIVO ESTOY USANDO HTML Y CSS PURO, SIN BOOTSTRAP NI NINGÚN OTRO FRAMEWORK, PARA EVITAR PROBLEMAS.

acá esta parte de mi código:

```html
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="width: 100%;  display: inline-block; position: relative; text-align: center;">
          <!-- <div style="width: 250px;"> -->
            <!-- <div style="text-align: left; display: inline-block;"> -->
              <!-- <div style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; padding: 0 5px;"> -->
              <div style="height: 230px; width: 250px; display: inline-block;">
                <div style="display: inline-block;width: 250px; text-align: center; ">
                  <a [href]="${config.link_api_whatsapp}" target="_blank"><img class="mr-1" style="width:40px; margin-top: 0px;" src="https://www.eldatodemiamiga.cl/assets/iconos/icono-whatsapp.png"></a>
                <!-- </div> -->
                <!-- <div style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; padding: 0 5px;"> -->
                  <a [href]="${config.link_facebook}" target="_blank"><img class="mr-1" style="width:40px" src="https://www.eldatodemiamiga.cl/assets/iconos/icono-facebook.png"></a>
                <!-- </div> -->
                <!-- <div style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; padding: 0 5px;"> -->
                  <a [href]="${config.link_instagram}" target="_blank"><img class="mr-1" style="width:40px" src="https://www.eldatodemiamiga.cl/assets/iconos/icono-instagram.png"></a>
                  
                </div>
                
              </div>

              <div style="display: inline-block; height: 230px; width: 250px; position: relative;">
                <div style="position: absolute;  text-align: height: 230px; width: 250px;  ">
                  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Fs1pSp5w/Planets-Saturn-planet-Planetary-ring-519623-1920x1080.jpg" alt="imagen de packs" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                  
                </div>
                
              </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            <!-- </div> -->
          <!-- </div> -->
          
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
```

y acá esta la imagen de como se ve ahora, y lo que quisero es que los 3 iconos de las redes sociales estén arriba (donde esta el ovalo rojo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas utilizando Boostrap 4 o alguno similar?

Comment: Html y css puro, ya que es una plantilla para un correo, si ves una clase por ahi de bootstrap es que se me escapó.

Comment: Luego de una leída a [este documento](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css)... Parece ser que mi respuesta usando `flexbox` no es aplicable para tu caso. También encontré [esto](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/flexbox/flex/).

Comment: Si, disculpa, voy a editar, ya que fué mi error no especificar que estoy trabajando en una plantilla para un correo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julian, te paso una aproximacion. Hay que ajustarlo un poco. Puedes usarlo como base.

```
<!-- MODULE ROW // -->
<tr>
 <td align="center" valign="top">
    <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
      <tr>
         <td align="center" valign="top">
            <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="flexibleContainer">
              <tr>
                 <td align="center" valign="top" width="600" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="50" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                         <td align="center" valign="top">

                            <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                 <td valign="top" class="textContent">
                                    <div mc:edit="body" style="text-align:left;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:0;color:#5F5F5F;line-height:135%;height: 230px; width: 250px;">
                                  <a [href]="${config.link_api_whatsapp}" target="_blank"><img class="mr-1" style="width:40px; margin-top: 0px;" src="https://www.eldatodemiamiga.cl/assets/iconos/icono-whatsapp.png"></a>
                                <!-- </div> -->
                                <!-- <div style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; padding: 0 5px;"> -->
                                  <a [href]="${config.link_facebook}" target="_blank"><img class="mr-1" style="width:40px" src="https://www.eldatodemiamiga.cl/assets/iconos/icono-facebook.png"></a>
                                <!-- </div> -->
                                <!-- <div style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; padding: 0 5px;"> -->
                                  <a [href]="${config.link_instagram}" target="_blank"><img class="mr-1" style="width:40px" src="https://www.eldatodemiamiga.cl/assets/iconos/icono-instagram.png"></a>
                               </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td valign="top" class="textContent">
                                    <div mc:edit="body" style="text-align:left;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:0;height: 230px; width: 250px;">
                                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Fs1pSp5w/Planets-Saturn-planet-Planetary-ring-519623-1920x1080.jpg" alt="imagen de packs" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                              </div>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->

                         </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                 </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
         </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
 </td>
</tr>
<!-- // MODULE ROW -->
```

concepto detrás del código

- mezclar lo menos posible secuencias de tags TABLE-TR-TD con DIV. No es que sean incompatibles, pero por experiencia te comparto que los primeros son mas compatibles con el html basico de los emails.
- siempre ubicar el codigo en tablas, anidadas y centradas. Eso facilita el responsive
- evitar codigos html del tipo display o position. Esos rompen el html y dejan librado a la interpretacion del cliente que lo reciba el formateo. Generalmente sale mal.
- Para posicionar usar celdas dentro de tablas anidadas, segun secuencia TABLE-TR-TD y alli utilizar align y valign para el posicionamiento.

Como siempre digo, no le pidas peras al olmo. El html de los emails creo que es version 1 o 2. Lejos está del html5 que disfrutamos en las paginas web.

Ojala te sirva

Comment: Me ayudó bastante. sabrás si el estilo margin-top -20px; es incompatible con estas plantillas? estoy implementando ese estilo pero no me funciona en Gmai.

Comment: yo utilizo padding en lugar de margin. A veces un mix de padding con line height funciona mejor.

Comment: lo que sucede es que es un contenedor que esta fuera del td de la tabla, y quiero que quede un poco encima del td, por eso le hago un margin-top negativo, pero no funciona, por mas que le aumente el valor no funciona.

Comment: margen negativo es mala palabra para los emails jaja. Sugiero que armes una row por encima de la tabla, creando una tabla de una sola fila y allí posiciones los iconos, entonces. Otra opción es que bajes el saturno, con un padding positivo.

Comment: no me sale, disculpame tendrás tiempo para una consulta en privado ?

Comment: si. estoy trabajando asi que no tengo problemas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119796/discussion-between-julianprog-and-claudio).

Answer (score 0):

Dado que parece ser debes trabajar con los estilos dentro de las etiquetas, puedes lograrlo de manera relativamente sencilla de esta forma:

- Al div que es contenedor de las imágenes de enlaces de redes sociales le puedes indicar que sea un elemento flotante a la ziquierda y que ocupe el 50% de ancho de su contenedor de esta manera:

  ```
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  ```

Usamos `text-align` con un valor de `center` para mover al centro vertical a los íconos de las redes sociales

- Al div que es contenedor de la imagen del planeta le puedes indicar que sea un elemento flotante a la derecha y que ocupe el 50% de ancho de su contenedor de esta manera:

  ```
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  ```
- Opcionalmente le puedes indicar una medida a la imagen de esta forma:

  ```
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  ```

Ya solo te queda a ti mover este CSS a tus etiquetas

Es importante hacer notar que el CSS anterior es el único que emplee para el resultado que buscas, entonces *puede ser que debas considerar remover algo de lo que ya tienes*

**Ejemplo**

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
       <div style="float: left; width: 50%; text-align: center;">
            <div>
              <a [href]="${config.link_api_whatsapp}" target="_blank"><img class="mr-1"  src="https://www.eldatodemiamiga.cl/assets/iconos/icono-whatsapp.png"></a>
               <a [href]="${config.link_facebook}" target="_blank"><img class="mr-1"  src="https://www.eldatodemiamiga.cl/assets/iconos/icono-facebook.png"></a>
          <a [href]="${config.link_instagram}" target="_blank"><img class="mr-1" src="https://www.eldatodemiamiga.cl/assets/iconos/icono-instagram.png"></a>
              
            </div>
            
          </div>

          <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
            <div >
              <img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" class="planeta" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Fs1pSp5w/Planets-Saturn-planet-Planetary-ring-519623-1920x1080.jpg" alt="imagen de packs" >
              
            </div>
            
          </div>
    </div>

  </td>
</tr>
```

**Lectura de referencia**

- [float css](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/float)